# Deleted Firefox tokens are still pushable through Mozilla Push Server

Tags: firefox, web-push

I am currently sending web notifications on Firefox desktop browsers.
Unfortunately, **deleted tokens are still pushable through Mozilla Push Server**.

To delete the token (i.e. the subscription endpoint), generated by the *ServiceWorker*, I just clear the cache history. Then, I send a notification to the deleted endpoint : Mozilla returns a `201 Created`, telling us the notification has been created for the user and ready to be send.

But if I repeat the same steps with a Chrome browser, Google Cloud Messaging tells us that the token is not registed (cf [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) > "Unregistered Device").

However, I can clearly see in [Mozilla documentation](http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#errors) that there are error codes for this situation : cf `errno 103 - Expired URL endpoint`, or `errno106 - Invalid subscription`.

Also, I must say that if I block the native notification permission, **previously granted**, Mozilla returns in consequence a `errno106 - Invalid Subscription` error. The problem is when the token has been deleted.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "the token has been deleted".  A token is "deleted", meaning that is no longer valid, when the user blocks the native notification permission.

Comment: @collimarco To put it plainly: a user has an endpoint and receives web push. But if he clears his browser cache, he won't receive web notifications anymore. So this endpoint becomes useless. I want Mozilla to tell me that I should never send to this endpoint anymore.

Comment: I agree with you. There are some cases when you don't know if the notification will be delivered. However this is a problem regarding the Push API specs or how Mozilla handles that: I don't think that here on StackOverflow someone can provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla has been working on this unwanted behavior : [BugZilla #1277615](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1277615)

It is now fixed with **Firefox Developer Edition v49** and it returns a `errno106 -  No such subscription` in this situation.